# Parse/extract URIs that may contain Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

As part of a Java webapp I'm working on I need to add a prefix to some URIs are loaded from a database, e.g.

```
"controller.jsp?page=list"
```

becomes...

```
<a href="${legacyBaseUrl}/controller.jsp?page=list">...</a>
```

Easy. A problem arises though where some of the URIs in the database contain Javascript, e.g.

```
"javascript:window.open('controller.jsp?page=popup')"
```

What I'd like to be able to do is...

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('${legacyBaseUrl}/controller.jsp?page=popup')">...</a>
```

or better yet...

```
<a href="${legacyBaseUrl}/controller.jsp?page=popup" target="_blank">...</a>
```

I know I can just chop it apart with regular expressions, but I'm wary of treating this as a simple string manipulation problem, as the data has never been sanitized and there could be any Javascript in the database.

Is there a (relatively) simple way to parse Javascript properly in Java, and recognize/extract calls to window.open or other JS function?

I've looked briefly at stuff like Rhino or javax.script, but am a bit lost. Is this the right thing for my needs? Would a regex actually be enough? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need fully functional HTML and probably java script parser. There are a lot such pure java implementations, e.g.

http://www.webrenderer.com/products/server/product/

HTML UNIT

http://lobobrowser.org/java-browser.jsp

Jakarta Cactus